# How to programmatically list all controllers and actions in RoR engines?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

This question is sort of an extension of what was brought up in this discussion: [How to programmatically list all controllers in Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1564278/how-to-programmatically-list-all-controllers-in-rails)

It seems most of the solutions for listing out an application's controllers and actions makes use of importing and parsing #{RAILS_ROOT}/app/controllers.

I've been building and making use of RoR Engines which are in #{RAILS_ROOT}/vendor/plugins/

How could these be included to list out every engine's controllers and actions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is pretty old, and rails 3 has changed a lot of things. I've had to go through about 3 different ways of doing this as things have changed. Currently on rails 3.2.2 this has been my best solution:

```
Rails.application.reload_routes!
all_routes = Rails.application.routes.routes

require 'rails/application/route_inspector'
inspector = Rails::Application::RouteInspector.new
for routeRule in inspector.format(all_routes, ENV['CONTROLLER'])
    # Parse routeRule to get your values
end
```

Comment: Hi i've got uninitialized constant Rails::Application::RouteInspector in production mode.

Answer (score 2):

Weird how just writing a question out can help you figure it out. I was able to get this working by simply including the engine's controllers by running:

```
Find.find(File.join(RAILS_ROOT, 'vendor/plugins/'))  { |name|  
    require_dependency(name) if /_controller\.rb$/ =~ name
}
```