# Rails 3: Separate javascripts for each action?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, view

I have an app where I keep track of different "Games". In the "show"-view, I would like to show the game information plus a select, which I can use to quick-jump to a game.

The quick-jump feature would obviously be some javascript but here's my problem: After some reading, I still don't get how I can have a separate javascript file for each action of a controller. I could add the code to the application.js but I think that would blow-up that file unnecessarily. Any link to a good basic guide for the interaction between Rails 3 and Javascript would also help very much. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to the following question spells this out a bit more specifically and with a helper method to make it a bit more elegant.  Same idea though:

[Rails 3.1 asset pipeline: how to load controller-specific scripts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6571753/rails-3-1-asset-pipeline-how-to-load-controller-specific-scripts)

Answer (score 1):

Just introduce separate javascript files per controller+action basis (e.g. CONTROLLERNAME_ACTIONNAME.js, replacing CONTROLLERNAME and ACTIONNAME with your actual names ;) ) and include them in your views with javascript_include_tag(CONTROLLERNAME_ACTIONNAME.js).

Comment: Thanks, that's what I did. I'm sure it's not the perfect Rails-way yet, but I might be slowly getting there.

Comment: I wouldn't use separate javascript files, since they all need to be cached separately too. You wrote it could blow up that file unnecessarily... about what sizes are we taking here?

Comment: the sizes are pretty small < 5K but it's still better for the "readability" I would say.