# How to make controller/view specific Javascript work in a Rails 3.1 production environment

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I am trying to create view/controller specific Javascript in Rails 3.1. I have followed the method from [Rails 3.1 asset pipeline: how to load controller-specific scripts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6571753/rails-3-1-asset-pipeline-how-to-load-controller-specific-scripts) and http://tech.thereq.com/post/10754558724/the-rails-3-1-asset-pipeline-in-the-real-world-jquery.

This works great in my development environment. However, it fails in my production environment. I get the message, ActionView::Template::Error (users.js isn't precompiled).

My user.js.coffee file inside the .../app/assets/javascript directory contains

```
//= require i18n/grid.locale-en
//= require jquery.jqGrid.min    
//
//= require grid_object.js
```

My index.html.haml file inside .../app/views/users contains

```
- javascript 'users'
...
```

My application_helper contains

```
def javascript(*files)
  content_for(:head) { javascript_include_tag(*files) }
end
```

My application layout file contains

```
%= yield(:head) %>
```

Lastly, my application.js file inside .../app/assets/javascript contains

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery-ui
```

What am I missing?

Comment: I figured out it has to do with the .../config/environments/production.rb with config.assets.precompile but unsure of the value. I tried config.assets.precompile << '*.js', but this has problems because it pulls in all the vendor javascripts including language specific js.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I decided to use a postfix (i.e. '_pc') for all my controller/view specific javascript that needed to be pre-compiled. The required changes are:

Inside my view, I used:

```
- javascript require 'users_pc'
```

I renamed my users.js.coffee file to users_pc.js.coffee

Lastly, I updated my .../config/environments/production.rb file to contain

```
- config.assets.precompile << '*_pc.js'
```