# Non global coffee script and asset pipeline

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, coffeescript, asset-pipeline

I have a coffee script `user.js.coffee`, that is only used in certain views. I achieved this by using the following answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/6795533/784318

Now I have excluded the script from the `application.js`. I also removed the `//= require_tree .` entry.

So my file is available here: `http://localhost:3000/assets/user.js` however, when I deploy this to the server the assets will be combined in one `application.js` so how can I make sure that the user.js will be available on production like so: `http://myserver.com/assets/user.js`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `environments/production.rb` (or the environment you need precompile to occur) uncomment or add this file to the precompile array:

```
# environments/production.rb

config.assets.precompile += %w( user.js )
```

Other entries might be already present, just add any other file that you need to access separately.

This file will not get compiled in one big `application.js` file and will be accessible separately as `user.js`

Comment: This looks promising. I will test that out on production. Do you know if I have to use `user.js.coffee` in my case?

Comment: `user.js` should work fine. At least it works in my case. It should pickup the `.coffee` by itself

Comment: @Oktav but the compiled file will have the name with fingerprint like ```user-e55bd5e3eb82fa4e8034af2883dc37e8.js``` so we can't definitely know the path to it.

Comment: @freemanoid You need to include that file via `javascript_include_tag "user"` in your view and it should include the file with the correct fingerprint. Also the fingerprint will change only if the content of the js file changes.

Comment: @Oktav but what if I need to post the link to this file on 3rd party resource? I need to know the link to do that.

Comment: @freemanoid If you need to use the same js file for other applications then I wouldn't use the asset pipeline for that file. Just write it as plain js, put it in public/javascripts/ and include it statically. Something like `javascript_include_tag "javascripts/user.js"`

Comment: @Oktav but I still want to use coffee for it

Answer (score 0):

You can try putting your user.js file to the public folder of your application directly and configure your asset pipeline to exclude it from the "zipping" process.

Comment: Well it is not a `.js` file but a `.js.coffee` file. So it will at least have to processed by the coffee-script compiler.

Comment: Check this http://scottwb.com/blog/2012/06/30/compile-a-single-coffeescript-file-from-your-rails-project