# Why content_for method undefined in rails view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, templates, yield, content-for

I have a rails project.

In the `application.html.slim` I have:

```
doctype html
html
  head
    title RailsMongoidPj
    = stylesheet_link_tag    "application", media: "all", "data-turbolinks-track" => true
    = javascript_include_tag "application", "data-turbolinks-track" => true
    = csrf_meta_tags
    meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" name="viewport"
    = yield(:html_head)
  body
    = yield
```

In a controller `SearchController`, which has a method:

```
  def javascript(*files)
    content_for(:html_head) do
      javascript_include_tag(*files)
    end
  end
  helper_method :javascript
```

Also this controller has a method `new` with a corresponding view, which content is:

```
= javascript('/vendor/assets/javascript/handelbars.runtime.js')

- content_for :html_head do
  script#entry-template type="text/x-handlebars-template"
    | template content
```

But I have an error:

```
undefined method `content_for' for #<SearchFlickrController:0x007f8e4f2bae78>

Extracted source (around line #3):

1  / search flickr api page
2  
3  = javascript('/vendor/assets/javascript/handelbars.runtime.js')
4  
5  - content_for :html_head do
6    script#entry-template type="text/x-handlebars-template"
```

Why the method is `content_for` undefined? Isn't it an standard `rails` method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`content_for` is a helper method. You use `content_for` in a view, not in a controller. Therefore the right place for a method using `content_for` is a helper (`app/helper/search_helper.rb` for example):

```
module SearchHelper  
  def javascript(*files)
    content_for(:html_head) do
      javascript_include_tag(*files)
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: do you know what to do to make it work and still having the method outside the view? I found this solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6571753/rails-3-1-asset-pipeline-how-to-load-controller-specific-scripts.