# How do I get the list of actions available for a controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I did `MyController.methods`
and it listed EVERYTHING... things I didn't even know controllers could do!

How do I return the list of actions, such as `create`, `edit`, `new`, `destroy`, `other_action`, `other_non_protected_or_private_method`?

Using Ruby on Rails 2.3.8

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Not sure if [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8686441/how-to-get-list-of-controllers-and-actions-in-ruby-on-rails) will work in 2.38 but I figured it was worth a shot:

To quote the relevant part:

To get all the actions in a controller, use action_methods

```
PostsController.action_methods
```

This will return a Set containing a list of all of the methods in your controller that are "actions" (using the same logic Rails uses to decide whether a method is a valid action to route to).

Answer (score 17):

Use #instance_methods(false) to retrieve only controller's specific actions:

```
CustomController.instance_methods(false)
=> ["index", "update", "show", "custom_action", "another_action"]
```

Hope this helps!