# Getting public methods from a controller via rails console

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have a controller and would like to get its public methods, but am confused about this result; there should be about ten methods:

```
IndexController.public_methods - ApplicationController.public_methods
# => []
```

Is this not calling what I think should be calling?

Comment: why are you doing subtraction?

Comment: subtract out what I think the public methods should be

Comment: I know what you're asking, but i just tried `action_methods` inside rails console, and it actually returns what i think you want

Comment: yep, thx, 15 minutes to accept ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a particular controller, you can use `action_methods`

```
ApplicationController.action_methods
```

[How to get list of controllers and actions in ruby on rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8686441/how-to-get-list-of-controllers-and-actions-in-ruby-on-rails)