# Iterating through controller methods in view

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to refactor some of the code in my view

```
<% if controller.controller_name == "overview" %>
<div id="left-menu">
    <ul>
    <li>Office</li>
    <hr>
    <li><%= link_to "Overview", root_path %></li>
    <li><%= link_to "Personnel", personnel_path %></li>
    <li><%= link_to "Results", results_path %></li>
    <li><%= link_to "Statistics", statistics_path %></li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
    <li>Economy</li>
    <hr>
    <li>Finances</li>
    <li>Contracts</li>
    <li>Transfers</li>
    <li>Sponsors</li>
    </ul>               
</div>
<% elsif controller.controller_name == "market" %>
<div id="left-menu">
    <ul>
    <li>Items</li>
    <hr>
    <li><%= link_to "Engines", market_engines_path %></li>
    <li><%= link_to "Weapons", market_weapons_path %></li>
    <li><%= link_to "Armor", market_armor_path %></li>
      <li><%= link_to "Chips", market_chips_path %></li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
    <li>Personnel</li>
    <hr>
    <li><%= link_to "Drivers", market_drivers_path %></li>
    <li><%= link_to "Servicemen" %></li>
    <li><%= link_to "Programmers" %></li>
    <li><%= link_to "Managers" %></li>
    </ul>               
</div>
<% end %>
```

Where each `<li>` corresponds to a method in the controller. I would like to be able to add new methods to my controllers, and then have them dynamically inserted in the view. So is there a way to iterate over the methods in a controller?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8686441/how-to-get-list-of-controllers-and-actions-in-ruby-on-rails ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the answer provided in the referenced question, `Controller.action_methods` seems to be the method you need, however, to integrate into your code is as follows:

```
<% lists = %w(items personell) %>
<% for list in lists do %>
    <ul>
        <li><%= list.titleize %></li>
        <hr>
        <% items = MarketsController.action_methods %>
        <% for item in items do %>
            <li><%= link_to item.titleize, eval("market_#{item}_path") %></li>
        <% end %>
    </ul>
<% end %>
```