# Rails: list controller actions in my (end descendant) class only

Tags: ruby-on-rails, inheritance, reflection

I want to list all public controller actions defined by me, but simple refering to `action_methods` member gives a list of all methods even derived from parent classes.

Comment: Try with `your_controller.descendants`

Comment: @Pavan: my controller is an end descendant itself and I want to list it's methods, but not methods of it's descendants. Please suggest a new question title if this is not clear.

Comment: Not quite clear but have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8686441/how-to-get-list-of-controllers-and-actions-in-ruby-on-rails?rq=1 might help you.

Comment: @Pavan: I've got my current decision from there, but it works as described above.