# Rails 3, get a list of all controller names from a model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, routes, controllers

My goal is to create quick urls for this one controller's views. Sort of like how some sites have domain/* mapping to viewing a user's profile. Beyond simply putting this rule in the routes rb at the end of the file, I would also like to prevent users from naming their URL as a controller inadvertently (or on purpose ha). So I need a quick way to grab all the names of the controllers and then I'll just write a custom validator in my model to tell the user that the specified url is reserved.

So how can I get a list of all the controllers?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1564278/how-to-programmatically-list-all-controllers-in-rails

Comment: I'm in development mode... ha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the risk of sounding trivial, I'd say perhaps you can try to add the controller names in a array somewhere and do a check before creating the new user? That way the app won't waste resources listing out the directory everytime a user needs to be created.

Comment: This is probably how it is going to need to happen when we scale up. For now I just read the directory, but once the code base stabalizes a bit more there would be nothing wrong with this approach.

Answer (score 1):

ActiveSupport adds a 'subclasses' property to the Class object, so you should be able to call ApplicationController.subclasses and get a list of all defined controllers. No guarantees this will be advisable.

Answer (score 0):

I found another way to do it. Is this a bad idea? I feel like, its better than loading all the controllers needlessly?

```
controller_list = Array.new
Dir["app/controllers/*.rb"].each do |file|
    controller_list.push(file.split('/').last.sub!("_controller.rb",""))
end
```