# Rails: HTML Table of Controllers and Actions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

Is there a way to make a table with a listing of all the controllers and actions similar to what you see in the rake routes?

Thanks!

Comment: Visit http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1564278/how-to-programmatically-list-all-controllers-in-rails

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there'a already a topic:
[How to programmatically list all controllers in Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1564278/how-to-programmatically-list-all-controllers-in-rails)

**one approach:**

```
routes= Rails.application.routes.routes.map do |route|
  {alias: route.name, path: route.path.spec.to_s, controller: route.defaults[:controller], action: route.defaults[:action]}
end
```