# Rails: list all links for new object creation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

Is there any elegant way of displaying a list of all links for new object creation?

Right now I solved it getting all routes with

```
routes= Rails.application.routes.routes.map do |route|
    {alias: route.name,
     path: route.path.spec.to_s,
     action: route.defaults[:action]}
end
```

taken from [How to programmatically list all controllers in Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1564278/how-to-programmatically-list-all-controllers-in-rails).

Then filtered and prepared links using

```
routes.each do |r|
    if r.reject { |k, v| v != 'new' } != {}
        puts %{<a href="#{r[:path].split('(')[0]}"> #{r[:alias]} </a>}
    end
end
```

I looked around and I guess there is no built-in method for this. Still, I'm looking for a shorter and more concise solution.

Comment: There is really no need for this. How often do your routes change? Create a partial with manually written links, then render the partial wherever you need it. When a route changes, edit the partial. This is the easiest, cheapest, and most maintainable way of doing it.

Comment: @gg_s Of course, routes rarely change. Still, they do. And apart from saving a minute here and there with this code you can't forget to update links and you are typo resistant as well :)

Comment: Forgetting to update a link is a careless mistake, albeit *a one-time fix*. Same for typos. If programmatic defenses are necessary to make up for lazy development, I can't imagine what happens when users are introduced. Seriously, this should not be done. Hence why it is so difficult to implement.

Comment: @gg_S Yes, these would be rather careless mistakes but I really don't see a reason here to abandon DRY principle and write everything twice. Automating this task makes your site more robust and saves time. Could you point out any advantages of having to prepare such list manually? or any sources advising against such practices?

Comment: Advantages: It's DRY, with one reusable partial. It's fast, with no compute→parse→render overhead. It fails gracefully, no code to debug. It's simple, reliable, maintainable, and it's based on default behavior. Disadvantages: It's boring.

Comment: @gg_s These arguments are much more convincing to me. Thanks!