# Application controller has no subclasses?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Just curious as to why this happens in the rails console:

```
Loading development environment (Rails 4.1.5)
2.1.2 :001 > require 'application_controller'
 => true 
2.1.2 :002 > ApplicationController
 => ApplicationController 
2.1.2 :003 > ApplicationController.subclasses
 => [] 
2.1.2 :004 > ::ApplicationController.descendants
 => []
```

I have this controller

```
class MyController < ApplicationController
end
```

So I'm expecting `ApplicationController.subclasses #=> [MyController]`, however, I'm getting an empty array :(

Comment: This answer and the first comment might interest you http://stackoverflow.com/a/1564401/976775

Comment: Because lazy-loading.

Comment: @MrYoshiji : I have tried the same in production mode `rails c -e production` and it returns the same.. `[]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, credit goes to MrYoshiji, but here's how you display subclasses.:

```
Loading development environment (Rails 4.1.5)
2.1.2 :001 > require 'application_controller'
 => true 
2.1.2 :001 > require 'my_controller'
 => true 
2.1.2 :002 > ApplicationController
 => ApplicationController 
2.1.2 :003 > ApplicationController.subclasses
 => [MyController]
```

Lazy load means an object doesn't exist in memory until it is specifically called during runtime. My second command, `require 'my_controller` actively references a subclass of ApplicationController and so it appears when we list its subclasses with the `.subclass` method.